# Using 'had risen' instead of 'rose', 'was growing' instead of 'grew'

Tags: tense, ielts

The question asks me to use the correct tense in the blank.

1. By 2007, UK household wealth ________(rise) from XX to just under XX billion Pound.

> **My answer: Rose ||**
> **Correct answer: had risen**

2. At the same time that the wealth of the govt and the household ___________(grow), the wealth of businesses declined.

> **My answer: grew ||**
> **Correct answer: was growing**

**I am not able to pinpoint what mistakes I made here, grammatically.
Can someone please tell me what is my mistake and what area of grammar should I practice/study more to avoid this kind of mistake in the future.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentence 1 refers to an ongoing process considered at a certain date (2007). We use the past perfect tense for an action that continued up to a certain time in the past.

Sentence 2 refers to two ongoing processes. The writer could also have put *...the wealth of businesses was declining*

Obviously, what you need to study is the use of tenses!

Answer (score 0):

The past perfect (had risen) indicates the past action has finished, whereas the simple past (rose) does not. Since the sentence says “by 2007”, the former is better.

I disagree with the second answer. Parallel verbs should usually agree in tense, and I don’t see anything here that indicates an exception where they shouldn’t. Since the sentence already has “declined”, I would use “grew”, as you did. If it had “was declining”, I would use “was growing”.